# Resizable draggable image goes to position:absolute when resized

Tags: jquery-ui

I have an image in this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/stevea/5S5NW/4/ - that I've made resizable and then I've made it draggable by applying draggable() to the ui-wrapper that resizable put around the image:

```
$(function(){       
    $('img#pelican').resizable({aspectRatio : true});
    $('img#pelican').closest('.ui-wrapper').draggable();
});
```

After resizable() and draggable() have first been applied the ui-wrapper has a position:relative style, as you can see with Firebug. And this remains as you drag the image around. But as soon as you start to resize the image the ui-wrapper style changes to position:absolute.  Why does this happen?

If I force the position back to relative with the button, it just goes back to absolute as soon as I resize it again.  If I leave out the draggable() line, so the image is just resizable, it works ok, i.e., stays position:relative after a resize.

Does anyone know what's going on here?  How can I create a resizable, draggable image that stays position:relative?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5S5NW/5/

You can find the resize event in this docu: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#event-resize

What I do is simple. While resizing I add css the css property position relative:

```
resize: function(){
  $(this).css('position', 'relative');
}
```

Keep in mind that theres a reason why jquery setting its position to absolute. Check the browsers and necessary functions if everything is orking as expected.